# findElementById finding every element in every tab

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Android application that uses 4 tabs:

```
Registry | Delivery | Invoice | Note
```

Every one of them is a Fragment loaded in a "container" activity.

In ContainerActivity I have a save button and, when I click it, I want to save everything from the tabs.
At this purpose I use `findElementById(R.id.myElementName)`.

Doing some debug I've noticed that this trick works only for loaded and pre-loaded fragment: if I'm in Registry fragment I can "find" only elements within RegistryFragment and DeliveryFragment, but not in InvoiceFragment.

How can I get EVERY element of EVERY fragment?

**SOLVED**

Thanks @Okas:
Using `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);` ('cause I have max 3 tabs excluding the one I'm rendering) make possible to reach every element within every fragment in my activity.

Comment: Why don't save a reference to each fragment on your activity when you create your tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

findElementById does not find elements from some fragments because these fragments are not created yet or are already destroyed.
You should use separate data objects to hold your important data and let fragments update these objects or alternatively try to increase ViewPager offScreenPageLimit so that fragments are not destroyed (this will increase memory footprint).